# Sum a column in a pandas dataframe where a condition is met in one column, but grouped by another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
        Ref_No  Definition  Total_to_Add
    0   ref1        B            20        
    1   ref2        A            30        
    2   ref1        B            40        
    3   ref2        A            50        
    4   ref1        B            60        
    5   ref2        B            50         
    6   ref1        B            60        
    7   ref2        B            50        
    8   ref1        B            60
```

For each reference, I want to sum Total_to_Add if they are 'B' and the same reference number (i'll have another column for A). There are 100's of reference numbers.

I can sum those that meet a single condition like this:

```
df['ANSWER'] = df[df['Definition']=='A']['Total_to_Add'].sum()
```

Or i can group by a reference like this:

```
df['ANSWER']=(df.groupby('Ref_No')['Total_to_Add'].transform('sum'))
```

But i can't seem to combine these functions, i.e. create a new column that totals up if the definition is 'B' and total by Ref_No.

I'm aiming for output like the below:

```
        Ref_No  Definition  Total_to_Add  Total_'B'
    0   ref1        B            20        240
    1   ref2        A            30        100
    2   ref1        B            40        240
    3   ref2        A            50        100
    4   ref1        B            60        240
    5   ref2        B            50        100 
    6   ref1        B            60        240
    7   ref2        B            50        100
    8   ref1        B            60        240
```

Any wisdom appreciated! Thanks

Comment: How did you arrive at 100 for ref2,A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Total_B'] = (df['Definition'].eq('B').mul(df['Total_to_Add'])
                 .groupby(df['Ref_No']).transform('sum'))
```

[out]

```
  Ref_No Definition  Total_to_Add  Total_B
0   ref1          B            20      240
1   ref2          A            30      100
2   ref1          B            40      240
3   ref2          A            50      100
4   ref1          B            60      240
5   ref2          B            50      100
6   ref1          B            60      240
7   ref2          B            50      100
8   ref1          B            60      240
```

Comment: This worked a treat - thanks! :) Is .eq('B') essentially the same as =='B'? what does .mul do exactly?

Comment: Yes `eq` method is same as `==`. `mul` is "multiply" - so multiplies the boolean (Definition == 'B') by the "Total_to_add" column... so `1` x "Total_to_add" if Definition is 'B' and `0` x "Total_to_add" if `!= 'B'`

Answer (score 2):

Replace non `B` values to `0` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['ANSWER']= (df['Total_to_Add'].where(df.Definition=='B', 0)
                                 .groupby(df['Ref_No']).transform('sum'))
print (df)
  Ref_No Definition  Total_to_Add  Total_'B'  ANSWER
0   ref1          B            20        240     240
1   ref2          A            30        100     100
2   ref1          B            40        240     240
3   ref2          A            50        100     100
4   ref1          B            60        240     240
5   ref2          B            50        100     100
6   ref1          B            60        240     240
7   ref2          B            50        100     100
8   ref1          B            60        240     240
```

Answer (score 1):

This will produce the sum of 'Total_to_Add' in 'Total_B' column if the 'Definition' == 'B'. `df['Total_B']=df[df['Definition']=='B'].groupby(by=['Ref_No','Definition'])['Total_to_Add'].transform('sum')`

Answer (score 1):

I will do `transform`

```
s=df['Total_to_Add'].mask(df.Definition!='B').groupby(df['Ref_No']).transform('sum')
s
0    240.0
1    100.0
2    240.0
3    100.0
4    240.0
5    100.0
6    240.0
7    100.0
8    240.0
Name: Total_to_Add, dtype: float64

df['New']=s
```